# Music spectrum visualization with better effects/graphics

Tags: c#, wpf, effects

I'm creating a music player in C# / WPF.

With the BASS audio engine, I can create simple spectrums like this:
[image: Simple spectrum example]

But I'm looking to create nicer looking ones like those seen in [YouTube videos created in After Effects](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=after+effects+audio+spectrum).

Are there any DirectX, OpenGL or other engines that can produce similar effects that I can use in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, your question isn't the best (fit wise) to SO, since it's not about a problem you have with code.

Having said that, WPF supports OpenGL, as you can see

- [Using OpenGL in a WPF Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265903/Using-OpenGL-in-a-WPF-Application)
- [Creating OpenGL Windows in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23736/Creating-OpenGL-Windows-in-WPF)

And also DirectX (although 9 it seems)

- [Walkthrough: Hosting Direct3D9 Content in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656785%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So, yes, you can choose your engine :)